# Google Plus API Authenticated User

Tags: php, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I have used the following code to authenticate a user (it is based off of googles examples of a services account on github):

```
<?php
//API INFORMATION
$client_id='xx-x.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_email='xx-xx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$client_key='xx';
$cert_loc='directory/google-api-bushbase-privatekey.p12';

//SET THE APP SCROPES
$scopes=array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
);

//GET ASSERTION CREDENTIALS
if(($key=file_get_contents($cert_loc))!==false){
    //GOT GOOGLE CERTIFICATE 
    try{
        $auth= new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($client_email,$scopes,$key);

    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo $error;
        echo 'Unable to get authenticate with Google servers</div>';

        //RETURN FALSE
        return false;

    }

}else{
    echo $error;
    echo 'Unable to get Google certificate</div>';

    //RETURN FALSE
    return false;
}

//GOOGLE CONNECTION OBJECT
try {
    $connection = new Google_Client();
    $connection->setApplicationName("Bush Base");
    $connection->setAssertionCredentials($auth);


    //CHECK TO SEE IF TOKEN IS EXPIRED VIA SESSION
    if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
      $connection->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
    }
    if($connection->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()){
        //TOKEN IS EXPIRED SO RESET WITH ASSERTION CRED
        $connection->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($auth);
    }

    //GET THE TOKEN VALUE
    $_SESSION['service_token']=$connection->getAccessToken();
    $connection->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);


//THE CONNECTION WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo $error;
    echo 'Unable to connect with Google database</div>';

    //RETURN FALSE
    return false;

}

//CREATE THE NEW GOOGLE SERVICES OBJECT
try{
    $info =new Google_Service_Plus($connection);

}catch (Exception $e){
    echo $error;
    echo 'Unable to conntect to google services</div>';

    //RETURN FALSE
    return false;
}

    try{
//GET THE USER INFO
$data= $info->people->get('me');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
  }
```

I am trying to get the information for the user account 103283326808099970387 but some how i am authenticated as user 111631880133159328429.

If i go to https://plus.google.com/111631880133159328429, I get a 404 error.

Comment: You are authenticated as the service account. Have you tried?  $data= $info->people->get('103283326808099970387');

Comment: i get the information however if i go another step forward and try  $data=$info->people-listPeople('103283326808099970387','visible');. i get an error as i can only get this information for the authenticated user $data=$info->people-listPeople('me','visible');

Comment: Why exactly are you using a service account and not Oauth2?

Comment: i do not want users to login i just want my account and use server to server controls

Comment: a service account is not you. You aren't going to see your account.

Comment: how can i get my account information without login. im thinking maybe  cURL alternative?

Comment: Hi, I have been revisiting this problem and have been trying to achieve similar results for web account however using this account i am forces to use oauth and i do NOT want to use it. I will be the only user and i want authorization to be automatically generated. i have been using cURL but i have zero luck. any help would be appreciated thank

Comment: You can NOT access a users data with out them giving you access to there data.  This is true even if the user is YOU.  You will need to authenticate your code once then you can reuse the refresh token as much as you like.  But you will still need to be Authenticated to access your data.

Comment: Hi, i realize they are seperate accounts and that i have authorized the service account. However, i just want to get my information without having the hassle of loging in. Essentially, ive designed a webpage that displays my info (and ONLY mine). This page is visible to my websites members and they can view the webpage and see my info. I am trying to figure a way i can bypass the OAuth login srceen and just get the info to display how i want